# NodeJS no response on submit

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have a local server running and an input form for users. I want when they press submit simply to output a message "Thank you!". Instead when pressing submit, nothing happens and after some time I get the message that the server dropped the connection. Could somebody help me please?

NodeJS:

```
var fs = require('fs');
const log=require('simple-node-logger').createSimpleLogger();
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
var port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/server'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.use('/images', express.static(__dirname +'/images'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile('main.html');
});

//app.listen(port, function(){
//    console.log('server is running on ' + port);
//});

app.post('/submit', function(req, res){
 console.log(req.body.rank);
});
```

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="/submit"  > 

      <img src="images/Picture1.png" style="width:280px;"/>
      <br />
        <select name="rank" size="1" style="width:80px;" required>
          <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Rank</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>


    <br />
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" id="submit"/>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your post handler does nothing

```
app.post('/submit', function(req, res){
  console.log(req.body.rank);
});
```

You can do the following action,

Redirect on another route with res.redirect :

```
app.post('/submit', function(req, res){
 console.log(req.body.rank);
 // redirect on /
 return res.redirect("/");
});
```

Render  a success html file:

```
 app.post('/submit', function(req, res){
 console.log(req.body.rank);
 // render success
 return res.sendfile('success.html');
});
```

Return json :

```
 app.post('/submit', function(req, res){
 console.log(req.body.rank);
 // render success
return res.status(200).json({message: "OK"})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Its happed because you in your post handler never produces any feedback to client, just log to console rank. Try something like

```
app.post('/submit', function(req, res){
 console.log(req.body.rank);
 res.json(req.body.rank);
});
```